# Programatically positioning a control in a VB.net user control

Tags: vb.net

I have a user control in VB.Net VS2019.  It is used to display a description, a value and units.  It generally works if the description is not too large.
The controls in the user control are all labels.

In the resize event it sizes the descriptions width to 66% of the overall width, 22% for the value, and whatever is left over for the units.
Then it set the description's left to 0, the value's left to the width of the description (plus a little). For the unit's position, it adds the left position of the value plus its width and a little.
But when the program runs the controls overlap each other and do not take the entire space of the UserControl.

For example the UserControl is 236 wide, but it looks like everything is squished to about 1/2 or 2/3s.
I have set Anchor to none and docking to none.

I perform these calculations in the 'Resize' event as shown below.  The code was ported from an old VB6 program.

Is the 'Auto' size property taking precedence over the width I specify?

```
    Private Sub UserControl1_Resize(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    Dim lblUnits_Size As Integer
    Label1.Height = MyBase.Height
    Label2.Height = MyBase.Height
    lblUnits.Height = MyBase.Height

    Label1.Width = CInt(MyBase.Width * 0.6167)
    Label2.Width = CInt(MyBase.Width * 0.22)  
    ' I want the width of the units to be whatever is left over 
    lblUnits_Size = MyBase.Width - (Label1.Width + Label2.Width) - 6
    If lblUnits_Size <= 0 Then lblUnits_Size = 1
    lblUnits.Width = lblUnits_Size  ' was -> TwipsToPixelsX(lbUnits_Size)

    Label1.Left = 0
    Label2.Left = (Label1.Left + Label1.Width) + 3
    lblUnits.Left = (Label2.Left + Label2.Width) + 3

End Sub
```

Comment: (Assuming WinForms, Tag your question specifying the UI platform): Use a TableLayoutPanel with proportional Columns, set the AutoSize property of the Label to `false`, dock the Labels inside the TLP's Cells.

Comment: I guess I thought VB.Net was specific enough. I do not know there was a difference. This is all like learning a completely new spoken language. Thanks. How many other UI platforms are there for VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the resize code needs to be called after the description changes. I guess ole VB6 did this automatically or someway the resize's were called after.

Comment: You don't need any code at all. Do as Jimi said and use a TableLayoutPanel. This is exactly the sort of thing it is for.

Comment: I sometimes need to change the % allocated space to each item. I have found that original allocation is not enough; so I would unless I am mistaken have to change a setting in the TLP to redo the percentages. I did not try the TLP.

Comment: The `TableLayoutPanel` has a `ColumnStyles` collection and each `ColumnStyle` has a `Width` property. You would presumably have the `SizeType` set tp `Percent`.